# Reconcile the principle axes, crystallographic axes, and some global axis for a polycrystalline uniaxial birefringent elastooptic material

Tags: material-science, elasticity, optical-materials

I'm trying to work out the tensorial algebra for elastooptic effects in a uniaxially birefringent material that has a polycrystalline grain structure. Let's denote a global reference frame $\{x,y,z\}$.

Now, for a grain with the crystallographic axis aligned with this frame, the Euler rotation angles are $\{\phi, \Phi, \psi\}$ = 0 for some rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}(\phi, \Phi, \psi) = \mathbf{Z}_1(\phi) \mathbf{X}_2(\Phi) \mathbf{Z}_3(\psi)$ (choose Bunge notation and a rotation about z, new x and new z axes). Then for grains *not aligned* with the global frame, it follows that the elastic stiffness tensor rotates as

$$C_{ijkl}' = R_{ir} R_{js} C_{rstq} R_{kt} R_{lq},$$

and similarly for the elastooptic tensors $p_{ijkl}$ since they must be collinear with the crystal. The change in the impermeability is

$$\Delta \beta_{ij} = p_{ijkl} \varepsilon_{kl}$$

for the symmetric elastic strains, $\varepsilon_{kl}$ that arise out of the stress-divergence problem solved in the *global frame*. Now, my question is, how is the grain orientation related to the indicatrix of the material?

The principle axes, is a new coordinate system (X, Y, Z) that transforms the dielectric tensor to have zero off-diagonal components as

$$\beta_{ij}^{-1} = \epsilon_{ij} =  \begin{bmatrix}
    \epsilon_{11} & \epsilon_{12} & \epsilon_{13} \\
    \epsilon_{12}   & \epsilon_{22} & \epsilon_{23} \\
   \epsilon_{13}   & \epsilon_{23} & \epsilon_{33}
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
    \epsilon_{\mathrm{XX}} & 0 & 0 \\
    0   & \epsilon_{\mathrm{YY}} & 0 \\
  0  & 0& \epsilon_{\mathrm{ZZ}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

This transformation is linear and orthogonal. Then one goes about defining the principle refractive indices

$$n_i = \sqrt{\epsilon_{ii}/\epsilon_0}. $$

For a crystal oriented along the global axes, the $i = Z$ component is the extraordinary index ($n_Z = n_e$), and the XY components are equal and ordinary ($n_X = n_Y = n_o$).

If I assume that the principle axis can always be aligned with the global axis (for now), then how are the principle refractive indices related to the Euler rotations of the misaligned grains? Do I first need to Euler rotate the dielectric tensor, and then perform the **same** linear orthogonal transformation that zeroes the off-diagonal components and then apply the change in impermeability? Thanks

EDIT: My confusion arises because the impermeability tensor ($\beta_{ij}$) is diagonal (due to the principle axis transformation of $\epsilon_{ij}$), but Euler rotated change in the impermeability ($\Delta \beta_{ij}$) will not be diagonal, so how does one extract something like the birefringence of a rotated grain?